# "Duplicating" entries SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that looks like

```
a
b
c
```

and I think I can select using some sort of a window function to get

```
a  1
a  2

b  1
b  2

c  1
c  2
```

but can't seem to find something suitable.

I know you can do this using a union but would prefer using a window function if it exists.

Comment: It's not a window function you want, it's a `CROSS JOIN` to the `VALUES` `1` and `2`.

Comment: _"I know you can do this using a union"_ - I don't see how a `UNION` can be used as a substitute for `ROW_NUMBER()` - set operations are orthogonal to windowing functions.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. Do you want to write it out so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you just want 2 rows, I would just `CROSS JOIN` to a `VALUES` table construct with the values `1` and `2` in it:

```sql
SELECT YT.YourColumn,
       V.I
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2))V(I);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.myColumn, x.N
from myTable t
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT TOP (2)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Object_ID) AS N
            FROM Master.sys.All_Columns t1
            CROSS JOIN Master.sys.All_Columns t2) x
```